# Recycle Bin Automated Data deletion Duration

Tags: administration, delete

The data in recycle bin is not deleted after 15 days automatically. Can anyone please help me understand the reason?

[image: deleted record including deletion date]

Answer (score 2):

In fact the deletion wasn't performed more than 15 days ago, as it occurred on 6th July 2017 according to your screenshot and today is 14th July. So only 8 days passed since deletion.

> Deleted records remain in the recycle bin for 15 days, and can be restored during that time. To permanently remove your deleted items before the 15-day period, administrators and users with the “Modify All Data” permission, can click Empty your Recycle Bin or Empty your organization’s Recycle Bin. After 15 days, deleted items are purged from the recycle bin, and once purged, they can’t be recovered.
> (Source: [View and Purge the Recycle Bin](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=home_delete.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=208.13))

Comment: oh my bad ....but i am facing a isue where the reports deleted on 15th june and was still present till 10th of july until it was manually deleted. Any Idea???